# What is flutter.minSdkVersion?

Tags: android, flutter

When I created a new flutter app, the content of `android\app\build.gradle` is

```
...
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app_name"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
...
```

What is `flutter.minSdkVersion`? Where it comes from? How do we know the actual value of it?

Comment: It must be coming from flutter framework based on what flutter version is being used for compatibility related issues between android and flutter. Look for local.properties file where they are written by flutter build system when you compile app.

Comment: I believe it comes from this file: `flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flutter.minSdkVersion value is coming from your installed flutter SDK's flutter.gradle file which is located inside `your_flutter_sdk/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`

In Simple words flutter.minSdkVersion is your project will support from that android version. If you want to change for particular project then you can replace flutter.minSdkVersion with 18 or other SDK number you want.

[image]